# can not add google account to emulator

Tags: android, account

I'm trying to add Google account to Emulator, Google API 2.2, but after filling my real Google's account details, i got the following message -

> "Can't establish a reliable data connection to the server."

How it can be solved? I'm not behind proxy.
Eyal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're following a tutorial for replacing the `system.img` file of the emulator with a custom system file, which lets you log in and access the Android Market, etc.

Not all of the system files work, however you can download one for api 1.5 [here](http://www.4shared.com/file/147420185/da5381e1/avd.html), or for 1.6 [here](http://www.4shared.com/file/165624746/fc72c3ed/system.html).

Comment: I also recommend creating a new Google account for testing, since I don't know the origin of these files, and who knows who you may be giving your login info when you use your own username/password.

Comment: I'm trying to debug C2DM application.